# Number of polynomials of degree less than 4 satisfying 5 points

Tags: polynomials

Let polynomial $P(x)$ have the property that $P(1),$ $P(2),$ $P(3),$ $P(4)$ and $P(5)$ are equal to $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$ in some order. How many possibilities are there for the polynomial $P,$ given that the degree of $P$ is strictly less than $4$?

Comment: Try to do this by assuming the degree of the polynomial P(x) by 3,2,1

Answer (score 18):

By Lagrange interpolation, given the values of $P(1)$, $P(2)$, $P(3)$, $P(4)$, and $P(5)$, there is a unique polynomial of degree $\leq 4$ taking those values.  So the question is, for which permutations of the numbers $1$ through $5$ will the resulting $P(x)$ actually have degree $<4$?  To determine this, we can look at the actual explicit formula for Lagrange interpolation and see what the coefficient of $x^4$ will be in terms of our five values.  That formula is 
$$\begin{align*}P(x)=P(1)\frac{(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)}{(1-2)(1-3)(1-4)(1-5)}&+P(2)\frac{(x-1)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)}{(2-1)(2-3)(2-4)(2-5)}\\
&+P(3)\frac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)(x-5)}{(3-1)(3-2)(3-4)(3-5)}\\
&+P(4)\frac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-5)}{(4-1)(4-2)(4-3)(4-5)}\\
&+P(5)\frac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}{(5-1)(5-2)(5-3)(5-4)},
\end{align*}$$
so the coefficient of $x^4$ will be $$\frac{P(1)}{24}-\frac{P(2)}{6}+\frac{P(3)}{4}-\frac{P(4)}{6}+\frac{P(5)}{24}=\frac{P(1)-4P(2)+6P(3)-4P(4)+P(5)}{24}.$$  So we get a polynomial of degree $<4$ iff $$P(1)+6P(3)+P(5)=4(P(2)+P(4)).$$

Now we just have some casework to consider.  If $P(3)=1$, the RHS will be at least $4(2+3)=20$ and the LHS is at most $5+6+4=15$, so there are no solutions.  Since the problem is symmetric with respect to conjugating by $x\mapsto 6-x$, there are no solutions with $P(3)= 5$ either.

If $P(3)=2$, then $P(1)+P(5)$ is divisible by $4$, which means $P(1)$ and $P(5)$ must be $1$ and $3$ (in some order) or $3$ and $5$ (in some order).  The equation will hold in the second case but not the first case.  This gives four different solutions, since you can swap the two values of $P(1)$ and $P(5)$, and also the two values of $P(2)$ and $P(4)$.  Again, by symmetry there are four more solutions if $P(3)=4$.

Finally, suppose $P(3)=3$.  Then $P(1)+P(5)$ must be $2$ mod $4$, so $P(1)$ and $P(5)$ must be $1$ and $5$ (in some order) or $2$ and $4$ (in some order).  Both cases work, and each gives four solutions.  Thus there are eight solutions total if $P(3)=3$.

Taking all the cases together, then, we find there are sixteen different solutions.

---

*Some closing remarks*:  It's not a coincidence that the coefficients of the values of $P$ in the equation we got are binomial coefficients; you can see this by noticing that the denominator in the Lagrange interpolation term with $P(n)$ is $\pm(n-1)!(5-n)!$ (grouping the positive and negative factors together), and this generalizes if you replace $5$ by another positive integer.  Still, it would be nice to have a more conceptual explanation for why we're getting binomial coefficients.  It would also be nice to have a more conceptual explanation for how to count the solutions (in particular, something that would generalize if you replaced $5$ by any positive integer).

Comment: The answer to some of your closing remarks comes from considering the finite-difference operator $\Delta(p) := p(x+1)-p(x)$. For polynomials of degree 4, $\Delta^4 = p(x+4)-4p(x+3)+6p(x+2)-4p(x+1)+p(x)$ is a constant, and for polynomials of degree $3$ $\Delta^3$ is constant and hence $\Delta^4$ is zero. So to check if the constant is zero we just have to compute it for one value of $x$, for instance $x=1$. All of this generalizes to an arbitrary degree.

Comment: now is 12 or 16 correct ? Where are the other 4 cases in the computational variant ?

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful: The number $12$ that copper.hat found is the number of cases you need to check _up to symmetry_.  Each solution you find among these cases actually gives you $4$ different solutions in general, by swapping the values of $P(1)$ and $P(5)$ or the values of $P(2)$ and $P(4)$.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful: I added a clarification to my approach above.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a computational approach:

Let $\pi \in \mathbb{R}^4$ represent the coefficients of a polynomial $p$  of degree
$3$ or less. That is, $p(x) = \sum_{k=1}^4 p_k x^{k-1}$.

Define $A$ by $[A]_{ij} = i^{j-1}$, $[a]_j = 5^{j-1}$ for $i=1,...,4$ and $j=1,...,4$. 
Note that $A$ is invertible.

Let
$(b,\beta)$ be a permutation of $\{1,...,5\}$ with $b \in \mathbb{R}^4$.

Then there is a polynomial whose values at $1,...,5$ are $(b,\beta)$
**iff** $A \pi = b, a^T \pi = \beta$, or equivalently,
**iff** $a^T A^{-1} b = \beta$ **iff** $(a^T A^{-1},-1) (b, \beta)^T = 0$.

A quick computation shows that $(a^T A^{-1},-1) = (-1,4,-6,4,-1)$.

Grinding through the permutations gives $16$.

```
# python...
import itertools
total = 0
for x in itertools.permutations(xrange(1,6)):
    if 4*(x[1]+x[3])-(6*x[2]+x[0]+x[4]) == 0:
        total = total +1
print total
```

While Eric's case analysis is more thorough, we can cut the number
of cases to consider down fairly quickly by looking at the vector
$(-1,4,-6,4,-1)$.

Any permutation that swaps elements $1,5$ or $2,4$ will produce the same result, so we can assume $\pi_1< \pi_5$ and $\pi_2< \pi_4$ and multiply the
resulting count by $4$.

If $(-1,4,-6,4,-1) \pi = 0$ then we see that $\pi_1+\pi_5$ must be even.

This shows that $\pi_1, \pi_5$ are restricted to
$(1,3), (1,5), (2,4), (3,5)$, and since $\pi_2< \pi_4$, we have a total of
$12$ cases to consider.

**Clarification**: As Eric (and the above computation, if you trust it) has shown the answer is 16. My comments above are just pointing out that if one
was to do the problem by hand using the above technique, one would need to check 12 cases. After checking these, we would find that only 4 work, so the
total number of cases is $4 \cdot 4 = 16$.

Eric's answer is more precise, mine is a lazier (from an intellectual
standpoint) approach.

Answer (score 2):

Well, given $n$ points, the only polynomial $P$ with $deg(P) < n$ that interpolates the points is the [Lagrange Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

This means there's only one polynomial for each way of ordering $1,2,3,4,5$. In conclusion, there are $5!$ possible polynomials that interpolate the points. Most of the time, these polynomials will have degree $n-1$, so it will depend on the values interpolated. For a concrete case, you can compare each Lagrange Polynomial and see if the degree matches your requirement.

Comment: The degree here is $<4$, not $<5$, so probably no $P$ will exist for most orderings.

Comment: My bad. Edited.

Comment: But, if they'd be the same, they would coincide in every value $P(i)$ for $i =1,2,3,4,5$ right? So the ordering would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Given information is that the function permutes the 5 numbers $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. So these  permutations extended as a polynomial will give rise to 120 distinct polynomials; but if you want the degree to be  less than 4 (that is not 4), then some permutations are not possible.

Take the permutation [4,5,1,3,2]. See how many times it goes up and down.
A discretised graph looks like:$ /\backslash/\backslash.$ So 3 turning points. This needs a degree 4 polynomial. More such  permutations [3,4,2,5,1], [3,4,1,5,2], [1,5,3,4,2] (and their reversals too).  You can write a program that enumerates all permutations $\sigma\in S_5$, calculates differences $\sigma(j+1)-\sigma(j),\  j <5$ and count how many sign changes in these differences (that will be the number of turning points).

Comment: This gives a necessary but not sufficient condition for a polynomial to work: even if there are $<3$ turning points, you may not be able to get a polynomial of degree $<4$.

Comment: @EricWofsey: I checked it. You are right. It is not sufficient.

Answer (score -3):

There are only one polynomial of degree 1 . There are three cases

> **Case 1** the degree of the polynomial is 1
>   If we let the degree of the polynomial is 1 then let the polynomial is P(x)=ax+b . Then put the values & solve it. The polynomial became P(x)=x .
>   **Case 2** the degree of the polynomial is 2. 
>   If the degree of the polynomial is 2 then let the polynomial is $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ . Again solve this you get the previous polynomial P(x)=x 
>   **Case 3** the degree of the polynomial is 3
>   Similarly you get the polynomial P(x)=x .
>   So there exist only one polynomial.

Comment: How do you explain $P(x)=6-x$ then?

Comment: If the ordering is not $1,2,3,4,5$ or $5,4,3,2,1$ no polynomial of degree 1 will interpolate the points, since every polynomial of degree 1 is decreasing or increasing. Also  this shows that there are minimum two polynomials possible, for the previous orderings, $P(x) = x$ and $Q(x) = 6 -x$. There definitely are more than one polynomial.